# Sort String s2 using the order of String s1 using either of comparable or comparator interface

Tags: java, string, comparator, comparable

i have two strings s1 and s2 and i would like to sort s2 based on the order of appearance of letters in s1 and if other alphabets are left in s2 sort them alphabetically.

Assume i have the following;

String s1 = "war";

String s2 = "Its awesome being a programmer";

output: waaarrrIbeeeeggimmmnoopsst.

I have written a code to do that already though buut i was wondering if its possible using the comparator/comparable interface to solve it.

Listed below is my code snippet.

```
public class Sort {

    private static String a = "war";
    private static String b = "Its awesome being a programmer";
    static List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        Character s;
        Character x;

        System.out.println("String to be sorted: '" + b + "'");
        System.out.println("Key for sort: '" + a + "'");

        /* 
         * put all the string in a list 
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
            s = b.charAt(i);
            if (s != ' ') {
                list.add(s);
            }
        }
        /* 
         * compare individual chac in key with individaul char in string to sort 
         */
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length(); j++) {
            x = a.charAt(j);
            for (int k = 0; k < b.length(); k++) {
                s = b.charAt(k);
                if (x == s) {
                    sb.append(s);
                    list.remove(x);
                }
            }
        }

        /* 
         * check if list is empty if not, sort and append the rest to the stringbuilder 
         */
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            Collections.sort(list);
            for (char c : list) {
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sorted version of string: '" + sb.toString() + "'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static String a = "war";
private static String b = "Its awesome being a programmer".replace(" ","");
private static String answer = "waaarrrIbeeeeggimmmnoopsst";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> characters = new ArrayList<String>(b.length());
    for (int i=0;i<b.length();i++){
        characters.add(String.valueOf(b.charAt(i)));
    }
    Collections.sort(characters,new CompareIt(a));
    String sortedString = listToString(characters);
    System.out.println(sortedString);
    System.out.println(answer);
    System.out.println(answer.equals(sortedString));
}
private static String listToString(List<String> listOfStrings){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String str : listOfStrings){
        builder.append(str);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
private static class CompareIt implements Comparator<String>{

    private final String source;

    public CompareIt(String source) {
        super();
        this.source = source;
    }

    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        int i1 = source.indexOf(o1);
        int i2 = source.indexOf(o2);
        if (i1==-1 && i2!=-1){
            return 1;
        } else if (i1!=-1 && i2==-1){
            return -1;
        } else if (i1!=-1 && i2!=-1){
            return i1 > i2 ? 1:-1;
        } else {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    }

}
```

This seems to work.
EDITED: To include sysout that result matches expected answer provided in question.
EDIT2: Typo with final indexed comparison I had ? 1:0 instead of 1:-1.

Comment: it doesn't seem to give the desired output

Comment: Sorry whats wrong with it, when I run it I get [w, a, a, a, r, r, r, i, b, e, e, e, e, g, g, i, m, m, m, n, o, o, p, s, s, t] which matches what you have above.

Comment: this is the result i got from it [a, w, a, r, r, a, r, I, b, e, e, e, e, g, g, i, m, m, m, n, o, o, p, s, s, t]

Comment: This is what i got again

awarrarIbeeeeggimmmnoopsst

waaarrrIbeeeeggimmmnoopsst

false

Comment: Apologies. My final comparison where both items are indexed was incorrect. I had 0 indicating equality instead of -1. I'll have to look into why this worked for me and not for you.

Comment: I edited the comparison and it worked  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            int i1 = source.indexOf(o1);
            int i2 = source.indexOf(o2);
            if (i1 == -1 && i2 == -1) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            } else {
                if (i1 == -1 && i2 != -1) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (i1 != -1 && i2 == -1) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return i1 - i2;
                }
            }

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "war";
    String s2 = "Its awesome being a programmer";
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        int len = s2.length()
                - s2.replace(String.valueOf(s1.charAt(i)), "").length();
        s2 = s2.replace(String.valueOf(s1.charAt(i)), "").replace(" ", "");
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
            result = result + String.valueOf(s1.charAt(i));
    }
    char[] remaining = s2.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(remaining);
    for (Character c : remaining)
        result = result + String.valueOf(c);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Try this: I tried without using any interface.

Output:

```
waaarrrIbeeeeggimmmnoopsst
```

Comment: Cool, but won't it be too much of over head on the jvm since strings are supposed to be immutable. Moreso, the running time is still O(n^2). i though probably with the use of any of those interfaces, i could achieve something better.

Comment: @Ayodeji I didnt read your question fully and started coding. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Comparator<Character> compareOn(final String key) {
    return new Comparator<Character>() {
        public int compare(Character c1, Character c2) {
            final int indexInKey1 = key.indexOf(c1);
            final int indexInKey2 = key.indexOf(c2);
            final int result;
            if (indexInKey1 == -1 && indexInKey2 == -1) {
                result = c1.compareTo(c2); //fall back to natural ordering
            } else {
                if (indexInKey1 == -1) {
                    result = 1;
                } else if (indexInKey2 == -1) {
                    result = -1;
                } else {
                    result = indexInKey1 - indexInKey2;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    };
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String a = "war";
    final String b = "Its awesome being a programmer";
    final List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (char c: b.toCharArray()) {
        if (c != ' ') {
          chars.add(c);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(chars, compareOn(a));
    System.out.println(chars);
}
```